# eclipse can not format the html file

Tags: eclipse, html-editor

I am using eclipse-jee-helios-SR1-win32,I found that it can not format the html file well,please check this img(this is effection after I use the "ctrl+shift+F"):

[image]

As the img shown , it does not format the file perfectly. The body tag should be indented.

I have not set any setting about the HTML-editor,all of the configuration are default.

Also I just did not install any plugins expect the Spoket.

So I wonder why?

This is the file formatted by the NetBeans, it work well, however I do not like that IDE.
[image]

Comment: But it does something? So it can't be a broken key binding?

Comment: Not the key,the ul and li tab are indented well.

Answer (score 0):

So it **is** formatted, just not to your liking?